# NGINX module wrapper for external software

Tags: nginx, load-balancing

I am looking into customizing the behavior of our NGINX load balancers dynamically per request. Basically I want like to do things like filter bad requests, dynamically determine the upstream server based on some custom external code and do some custom stats/logging.

I figure the only way to accomplish this is using a module, but I am not experienced in writing C/C++ code, and lots of the decision-making code I want to run partially exist in other systems already (C# code specifically).

**Is there a NGINX module (free, preferably) that can offload request-based decisions to external software, via TCP, pipe or similar?**

The closest I have found is the `ngx_http_auth_request_module` that can make a HTTP subrequest, but it can only be used to determine authentication status in a yes/no manner, not to select upstream server etc.

Comment: I think you want to engineer the wheel again...? why don't you tell the business related question or problem your facing? at the current point the question is nearly half off topic due development is not on topic for serverfault.com but might be on topic on stackoverflow.com. so precisely wrote what you need.

Comment: I was hoping there was a module for this, but you are right, that it might be more of a SO question instead then.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution via the LUA script module and created a script to call our own HTTP API for decision-making.

LUA module:
https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module

Stackoverflow post I used for inspiration:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48348647/fetch-information-from-an-api-before-sending-the-request-upstream